# etree schematron validation extends tag

Tags: python, xml, validation, lxml, schematron

I am trying to validate an xml by using a group of schemas which a schema that includes the others.

Main schematron :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <sch:schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sh="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" 
            xmlns:ef="http://www.efatura.gov.tr/envelope-namespace">

    <sch:include href="UBL-TR_Codelist.sch#codes"/>
    <sch:include href="UBL-TR_Common_Schematron.sch#abstracts"/>    

    <sch:ns prefix="sh" uri="http://www.unece.org/cefact/namespaces/StandardBusinessDocumentHeader" />
            <sch:ns prefix="ef" uri="http://www.efatura.gov.tr/package-namespace" />
    <!-- .... -->


    <sch:pattern id="document">
        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocument">
            <sch:extends rule="DocumentCheck"/>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>

      </sch:schema>
```

Common schmatron:

```
    <sch:schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
            xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron">

    <sch:pattern name="AbstractRules" id="abstracts">
        <sch:p>Pattern for storing abstract rules</sch:p>

        <!-- Rule to validate StandardBusinessDocument -->
        <sch:rule abstract="true" id="DocumentCheck">
            <sch:assert test="sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader">sh:StandardBusinessDocumentHeader zorunlu bir elemandır.</sch:assert>
            <sch:assert test="ef:Package">ef:Package zorunlu bir elemandır.</sch:assert>
        </sch:rule>

    </sch:pattern>
</sch:schema>
```

The problem is that, in main schema, if i put a directly assertion tag, for example:

```
 <assert test="sum(//Percent)=100">Sum is not 100%.</assert>
```

between "rule" tags, like that:

```
<sch:pattern id="document">
        <sch:rule context="sh:StandardBusinessDocument">
            <assert test="sum(//Percent)=100">Sum is not 100%.</assert>
        </sch:rule>
    </sch:pattern>
```

Than the etree's isoschematron.Schematron class validates my main schematron. Else it throws an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\SUNUCU\validate\v.py", line 102, in <module>
  schematron = etree.Schematron(s)
File "schematron.pxi", line 116, in lxml.etree.Schematron.__init__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:156251)
SchematronParseError: Document is not a valid Schematron schema
```

I've tried it with etree.Schematron class and it throws "SchematronParseError: invalid schematron schema:" too.

I am thinking that the problem is about schematron's

```
  <sch:extends />
```

tag. I mean, errors appear when schematron use an external assertion of rule.

What is the correct way working with related and united schematrons by using python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I stopped to try to do it with etree and I solved the problem by using [Probatron4j](https://code.google.com/p/probatron4j/) with python subproces.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was much simpler:
it seems like you forgot the "sch:" XML-namespace prefix in the `<assert>` element.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the files contain that namespace prefix on main schematron.("xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" )
And i dont think the problem is in schematron, because the same schematron works well with java [probatron4.jar](https://code.google.com/p/probatron4j/)